# postgres COPY (...) TO PROGRAM on Windows giving error

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd, psql, pg-dump

I am trying to dump PostgreSQL tables using a COPY statement. I am using COPY instead of pg_dump because I need to perform a transformation on one of the columns as it comes out.

The statement I would like to execute is essentially this

```
COPY ( SELECT 'punt' ) TO PROGRAM '7z a -si C:/Users/Public/Documents/punt';
```

but I am getting the generic error

```
ERROR: program "7z a -si C:/Users/Public/Documents/punt" failed
DETAIL: child process exited with exit code 1
```

I am trying to pass the `COPY` output through 7zip similar to [the fourth example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html#AEN69202) in the `COPY` documentation in order to compress the output as the database is about 130 GB and I'm ideally working with SSDs. The following command works fine:

```
COPY ( SELECT 'punt' ) TO 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/punt';
```

with result `COPY 1`. I have executed the following command on the psql prompt and it also works which makes me fairly confident about syntax and permissions:

```
\! echo 'punt' | 7z a -si C:/Users/Public/Documents/punt
```

Am I missing something about the `cmd` pipeline or the 7zip executable permissions?

**EDIT:** Postgres version is 9.3.3

I'm still getting the same error after changing the dir permissions to `NETWORK SERVICE` based on Craig Ringer's answer. This, however, did not fix the problem and the error is identical. Even after changing the target directory's permissions giving full control to `Everyone`, I still got the same error. I also tried changing the permission on the 7zip executable and the 7zip `Program Files` Directory to no avail.

In experimentation, I ran the following, taking the input from copy out of the equation:

```
COPY ( select '1' ) TO PROGRAM 'echo punt | 7z a -si C:/Users/Public/Documents/punt';
```

and curiously got the failure message, but instead with exit code 255, which for 7zip [has the meaning](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm) "User stopped the process". Can't seem to find a reason for this myself.

Comment: `\!` does not report or care about the exit status of the command, while `COPY...PROGRAM` does.  Are you sure it actually works in your last example?

Comment: @jjanes It definitely does. Before the command, `punt.7z` does not exist and after the command, it does. In fact, I _do_ see the output when running via `\!` identical to the output when running straight from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strikethrough the 7zip bit in my edit, the 255 error code is actually from `cmd` not finding the 7zip exe. I plopped `7zip.exe` on C:/ (couldn't figure out escaping the space in Program Files) and ran

```
COPY ( SELECT 'punt' ) TO PROGRAM 'C:/7z a -si C:/Users/Public/Documents/punt';
```

and **this worked**. I'm guessing the `NETWORKSERVICE` user doesn't have the `path` environment variable loaded, but I'm not sure about that.

I set the permissions on `C:/Users/Public/Documents` back to its default and the `COPY ... TO PROGRAM` **still worked** so file permission wasn't an issue in *this specific case*. I would still look to Craig Ringer's suggestion first if I encountered a problem like this again.

Comment: Argh, *headdesk*. I should've thought of that, but was thrown by the *permission denied*.

Answer (score 4):

It'll be a permissions issue.

The PostgreSQL server runs as `NETWORKSERVICE` for 9.2 and above, or user `postgres` for 9.1 and below, by default. `COPY` runs server-side as the user PostgreSQL its self runs as.

Neither of these are likely to have the right to write to `C:\Users\Public\Documents`.

You'll need to grant the PostgreSQL service user the right to write there using the Windows security properties dialog, or choose another location it can write to.

It works with `\!` because `psql` is running as your user, which *will* have permissions to write there, and `\!` runs the command client-side as the user running `psql`.

Comment: Once again, Craig Ringer to the rescue :-)

Comment: Aha! I was worried about that. Unfortunately, it didn't work still. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. `CMD` doesn't recognize a path with spaces.
2. `COPY FROM PROGRAM` doesn't have access to `PATH` variables.

Just wrap your PROGRAM_NAME like RESOURCE_NAME in double apostrophes and you are done:

```
COPY ( SELECT 'punt' ) TO PROGRAM '"C:/Program Files/bla/bla/7z.exe" a -si "C:/Users/Public/Documents/punt"';
```